# Powerpack 10 shapes not displaying properly on a different sized screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb-power-pack

Hello Im trying to deploy an application I made on a different computer.
It appears that the screen has a different resolution.

When I run the form on another computer, all the Powerpack shapes on the form seem to be stuck at a fixed position on the form and as a result dont scale properly with the rest of the controls on the form.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a common problem as the shapes don't have a "Dock" property. One thing you could try is to use a table layout panel and code the size of the shapes to the size of the panels.